# Where does ganache store the Ethereum blockchain

Tags: ethereum, truffle, ganache

I'm actually using truffle with Ganache to do some development.

I would like to know where does Ganache store it's blockchain to see how much data is used by my test. Is it stored somewhere accessible on the pc ?

I'm using

- Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
- ganache-1.0.1-x86_64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TestRPC used to just be in memory. They only recently released support for writing the blockchain out to the file system. As far as I can tell, the in memory implementation is still the default behavior. If you want to find the blockchain files, you'd specify the location yourself with the `--db` option.

From their [release page](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/releases) (under v4.0.0):

> Because we backed the TestRPC via the filesystem, this means you can
>   now save your blockchain's data for later use. That's right, if you
>   close the TestRPC and reopen it later, say, you can start up right
>   where you left off. You'll need to use the new --db option (see the
>   README) to tell the TestRPC where you'd like the data saved. You'll
>   also likely want to use the --mnemonic option to use the same accounts
>   each time.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with ganache-cli and it worked. I tried with ganache as well but it seems that this is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 3):

With Ganache v2, there is a new feature allowing you to maintain different workspaces.  Each workspace can represent a different ongoing chain, and can be resumed by reading from disk at (just about) any time.

For example (on Windows) a workspace named "sample-spot" would be stored at 
`%AppData%\Ganache\workspaces\sample-spot\chaindata` (where `%AppData%` may be something like `C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\`).

Some additional details can be found in code [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/blob/develop/src/main/types/workspaces/Workspace.js) and documentation [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.1).

Comment: If on Mac sometimes Ganache breaks and a clean up by removing local files in `~/Library/Application Support/Ganache` helps (which is an equivalent of AppData).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `--db`, you need to use parameters `--mnemonic` and `--networkId`

Example:

`ganache-cli -p 7545 --mnemonic --networkId 100 --db .`

Ref: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/407#issuecomment-347663452

Comment: In my case I had to add a value for the --mnemonic section e.g. `ganache-cli -p 7545 --mnemonic "polar velvet stereo oval echo senior cause cruel tube hobby exact angry" --networkId 100 --db .` If you run the command multiple times confirm that the available accounts are the same each run